# Unable to load MySQL database via entity framework in VS 2019

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, console-application, visual-studio-2019

I know that there are a lot of questions in different communities. I have tried each and everything but still unable to load my database via the entity framework. The database I am using in `MySQL` and I am trying to load it using Entity Framework. But the window crashes from below window

[image]

I have installed all the latest versions as said [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html).

Below is my `app.config`

```
 <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
  </provider></providers>
```

**PS:** I am using the console application.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: When you say "But the window crashes from below window", what does that mean? How do you know there is a crash? Is there an error message?

Comment: No but the window shuts down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have [`MySql.Data.Entity`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/) installed. Uninstall that and replace it with [`MySql.Data.EntityFramework`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework) instead.

For more information, see the final comment on https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90114.

Comment: Should I also remove settings from `app.config`?

Comment: @Faisal Yes remove anything that references `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6`.

Comment: The best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From your reply to my comment, I understand that the Entity Data Model Wizard simply vanishes when you click Next.

What you are describing is a malfunction in Visual Studio. You should therefore repair Visual Studio. You can do this by running the Visual Studio installer and choosing the option to Repair, or failing that, uninstalling and reinstalling.

**EDIT** only do this if the standard resolution actions for the MySQL VS addin have not solved the problem. Visual Studio should handle addin failures robustly, displaying an informative message. However, per Bradley Grainger's comment below, it may fail to do so. In those cases a VS repair/reinstall will not help.

Comment: The malfunction is in the MySQL VS addin; you can see that this is not an infrequent problem: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89338 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90114 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91195 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70078. Repairing Visual Studio is unlikely to help.